# why are my tensorflow events files empty?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am running the tensorflow object detection API and using the SSD_mobilenet model.I have the model.cpkt as well as the graph.pbtxt in my training dir. But in my training dir I found that my events files are empty. It seems that no data was written to my events. Could anyone help me,please!!!

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow event files will be generated based on the summaries what we have added in code.

For example, suppose you are training a convolutional neural network for recognizing MNIST digits. You'd like to record how the learning rate varies over time, and how the objective function is changing. Collect these by attaching tf.summary.scalar ops to the nodes that output the learning rate and loss respectively. Then, give each scalar_summary a meaningful tag, like 'learning rate' or 'loss function'.

For example:

## Add a scalar summary for the snapshot loss.

tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

Please refer the below link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I recently trained my ssd_mobilenet model using tensorflow object detection API and I run the model in the google colab. If my trainging was stopped due to the time of the use of the colab. Is there any solution  to restore my model ?

Comment: You can start model training with the same configuration file ( same input directory) , it will pick up the latest checkpoint and continue from there.